# C# - get handle of window right beneath the active window?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Is it possible somehow to get the handle of the window below the current active window retrieved by `GetForegroundWindow`, z-order wise? In other words, the window that is beneath the current one, no matter its size and position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this pinvoke calls:

```
[DllImport("User32")] extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr hWnd); 
[DllImport("User32")] extern IntPtr GetNextWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);
```

and use this as parameter

```
uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
```

So first get the top window (or yours). After that call GetNextWindow and for the result handle again and again,... so you will get all windows

Comment: You can't actually call `GetNextWindow`, because it is a sub function of `GetWindow` (which should be called instead), a bit misleading. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next or previous window (z-order wise) with the [`GetNextWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

**EDIT:** I just read on pinvoke.net that `GetNextWindow` is a macro of `GetWindow`. So you might as well call `GetWindow` directly:

Code from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindow.html):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd uCmd);

enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint {
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
    GW_OWNER = 4,
    GW_CHILD = 5,
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
}
```